# Connect Hive with Spark running on local mode with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: apache-spark, intellij-idea, hive, localhost

I'm trying to use Scala/Spark code on IntelliJ in order to read a table created on Hive. I have installed Hadoop then Hive on Ubuntu and both are running correctly on my local environment.

Below, this is the code i'm trying to run on IntelliJ :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

// warehouseLocation points to the default location for managed databases and tables
val warehouseLocation = "hdfs:///user/hive/warehouse"

val spark = SparkSession
 .builder()
 .appName("Spark Hive Local Connector")
 .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
 .config("spark.master", "local[*]")
 .enableHiveSupport()
 .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._
import spark.sql

sql("SELECT * FROM test.employee").show()
```

After executing this code, i had an error saying that the table is not found. I also tried to set the 'warehouseLocation' variable to '/user/hive/warehouse' but it's still does not work.

I'm wondering if it's necessary to configure the metastore in the hive-site.xml file and then add the hive.metastore.uris to the configuration parameters of the SparkSession ? Other suggestions are welcome.

Thank you for your help !